# Avoid too many if else in the filters

Tags: c#, design-patterns, c#-4.0

I want the following code to execute when the *myString* is having either of these values A, B, C or D. Right now I know that I have these 4 values but in near future I can have more values in this set. 
My Code:

```
var result = MyBlRepository.MyBLMethod(myString);
```

The simple way to have n number of if else loops but it can grow when I have more values. What is the best way to handle this? Which design pattern should be best for it?

**EDIT:** I don't want to keep the filters here. I don't want want to modify the code of this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the Strategy pattern, as explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/52807/Design-Patterns-Part-1-The-Strategy-Pattern)

It allows you to handle multiple if statements nicely. There is a short and easy tutorial showing how to handle multiple if statements in the above link.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just checking whether `myString` has one of a set of constant values, you can simply use `switch`:

```
bool result;
switch (myString) {
    case "A":
    case "B":
    case "C":
    case "D":
        result = true;
        break;
    default:
        result = false;
        break;
}
```

Note that this is a particularly long version of this code:

- If you want to return a value based on the result of the comparison, you can just write `return true;`/`return false;` and omit the `break;` lines.
- If you want to check the value and throw an exception if it is not among the desired set of values (though an `enum` type might be more appropriate in this case), you do not need the `result` variable and just throw the exception in the `default` case (and `break;` is not needed in the default case any more).

Otherwise (if any of the values is not yet determined at compile time), do it the way described in the other answers with `List<string>`/`HashSet<string>`.

Comment: What is solution for "The simple way to have n number of if else loops but it can grow when I have more values." I know switch and if else

Comment: @RockySingh: Compared to the `List<string>`/`HashSet<string>` solution, this requires about the same number of lines and this can be optimized at compile time. P.S.: `if` has nothing to do with loops.

Comment: Well, the compiler can jump in and optimize the `switch` into the lookup in a precalculated structure. Or into a check like `myString.Length == 1 && myString[0] >= 'A' && myString[0] <= 'D'`. Or a sequence of comparisons if the compiler thinks it's faster. You need to leave the optimizations to the optimizer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = new List<string>
{
  "A", 
  "B", 
  "C",
  "D"
 };
 bool exists = list.Contains(myString);
```

Comment: ... and it's better to use `HashSet<string>`

Comment: @Vlad: ... well, for small sets definitely an overkill.

Comment: @Stefan: for small sets, it's a BCL's task to optimize the access, not the developer's.

Comment: @Vlad: it's not about the access it's about the data structure of the `Hashset<T>`. In my view it's the job of the developer to know the difference and the resulting impact of used data structures.

Comment: @Stefan: a developer should think in more abstract notions. `HashSet` is just _the_ structure with the fast O(1) lookup, and it doesn't matter how it is actually implemented. The underlying implementation may change, like it's the case for C++'s `std::map`.

Answer (score 0):

My seggestion is to use `Regex` with an external config file, you can use `app.cofing` or a `custom xml file`

you store possible values like this `expression = "^(A|B|C|D)$"`
then in your program :

```
var expression = ReadFromConfigFile(); 
var regex = new Regex(expression);
if(regex.IsMatch(myString))
 // do work
```